# Not able to make iPhone Project using Sudzc

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, wsdl, sudzc

I am not able to make iPhone project using `Sudzc`. Even if i am using the correct userName and password.
It's showing this error.

```
"Problems Generating Your Code.
The following issues were encountered while generating your code.
No WSDL files have been specified : Could not create WSDL"
```

I am stuck in this problem.

Comment: Did you upload a WSDL file to the site? Depending on endpoint security you may need to manually provide the WSDL for it to work.

Comment: what have you tried? the error is suggesting that you have not uploaded an actual WSDL file, have you? make sure you are uploading a WSDL file and not a XSD file by mistake.

Comment: @darvids0n I am using the url and then i am entering the username and password for it but still its showing the same error.

Comment: @bennythemink I am using the url link.

Comment: @Gourav.J I understand that. What you should do now is enter the URL in your web browser and save the response of that to a file on your computer. Use the Upload a WSDL function on SudzC and select the saved file. See if that works.

Comment: I second what @darvids0n said!

Comment: @darvids0n  Which file format i need to use for it? xml?

Comment: @darvids0n i tried doing it. still its not working.

Comment: @Gourav.J You should be able to save the file as a `.wsdl`. Sometimes you need to add `?wsdl` to the URL to actually get the WSDL file.

Comment: @darvids0n   I am using this url but to success.. http://123.136.128.19:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Maiyas%20Restaurant/Codeunit/iPhoneWS?wsdl

Comment: I can't help troubleshoot since I don't know the username/password (and please DON'T give them to me or anyone on this site). When you have the WSDL downloading properly then follow the above instructions. I won't be able to help you further on this, unfortunately.